# Rails 4 : unable to show individual orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to show individual items on my grocery app.

Using item.product.title & item.quantity.

because I want to do a subtotal of the orders. At the moment i get

```
NoMethodError in Orders#show - undefined method `product' for #<OrderItem:0x007fe53514d6e8>
```

orders.show.html

```
<h1>Your Order</h1>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <td><%= @order.user_id %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Status:</th>
        <td><%= @order.status %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Items:</th>
        <td><%= @order.order_items.count %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>

    <% @order.order_items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= item.product.title %></td>   <-----Error
        <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= item.product.price %></td>
        <td><%= print_price item.subtotal %></td>
    <% end %>

</table>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(@order) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', orders_path %>
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_numericality_of :price
    validates :stock ,numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to:  0 }

    has_many :order_items
end
```

order.item

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :Order
    belongs_to :Product

    validates :order_id, :product_id, presence: true
end
```

full error

```
NameError in Orders#show
undefined local variable or method `product' for #<#<Class:0x007fe539003568>:0x007fe5391abd48>
app/views/orders/show.html.erb:30:in `block in _app_views_orders_show_html_erb__2160818799905733439_70311241143160'
app/views/orders/show.html.erb:27:in `_app_views_orders_show_html_erb__2160818799905733439_70311241143160'
```

Comment: can you post full error also post your show action

Comment: posted error code and updated code

Comment: You haven't done yourself any favors by not following the Rails naming conventions, e.g., `belongs_to :product`. The error message is correct, you don't have a `product` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order item needs to be

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  validates :order_id, :product_id, presence: true
end
```

Easiest way to think of it, is that belongs_to is defining the method that returns the object associated with the join. So :product - to create order_item.product. Not :Product